# Constructing a c++ object in a specific memory location

Tags: c++

I am trying to run the constructor/default initializer of a class on a specific memory location.

I am trying to use pooling so I have allocated memory (with malloc) for the object and I have the address of where I would like to go.

I just don’t know how to run the constructor of the object on that void* location.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Read a lot more about C++ (it is a very complex programming language; few people master it entirely, and I certainly don't). I recommend a good book such as *[Programming: Principle and Practice Using C++](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/)* (by the main designer of C++, Stroustrup). Then see some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com) site and some standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (for C++11) or some newer version (like C++14 or C++17).

You want the [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), so to construct an object of class `Cla` with argument `1` at location of pointer `p` (declared `void*p;`) you code:

```
Cla*ptr = new(p) Cla(1);
```

BTW, if `SubCla` is a subclass of `Cla` (having an appropriate constructor of two arguments) you can of course have `Cla*ptr = new(p) SubCla(1, "x");`